# Why is my val_loss starting low and increasing does it even matters with transfer learning?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

Hey guys I am new to machine learning and I am running this code from https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-convolutional-neural-network-to-classify-photos-of-dogs-and-cats/

I want to understand why my val_loss starts low and then increasing. is this overfitting or under-fitting? also what can I use to improve the val_loss so it will give a better fit? in the blog post his cross entropy plot is a lot different from mine.  [image]

```
def define_model():
    # load model
    model = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    # mark loaded layers as not trainable
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    # add new classifier layers
    flat1 = Flatten()(model.layers[-1].output)
    class1 = Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(flat1)
    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(class1)
    # define new model
    model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=output)
    # compile model
    opt = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


# plot diagnostic learning curves
def summarize_diagnostics(history):
    # plot loss
    pyplot.subplot(211)
    pyplot.title('Cross Entropy Loss')
    pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], color='blue', label='train')
    pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], color='orange', label='test')
    # plot accuracy
    pyplot.subplot(212)
    pyplot.title('Classification Accuracy')
    pyplot.plot(history.history['accuracy'], color='blue', label='train')
    pyplot.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], color='orange', label='test')
    # save plot to file
    filename = sys.argv[0].split('/')[-1]
    pyplot.savefig(filename + '_plot.png')
    pyplot.close()


# run the test harness for evaluating a model
def run_test_harness():
    # define model
    model = define_model()
    # create data generator
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True)
    # specify imagenet mean values for centering
    datagen.mean = [123.68, 116.779, 103.939]
    # prepare iterator
    train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset_dogs_vs_cats/train/',
                                           class_mode='binary', batch_size=64, target_size=(224, 224))
    test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset_dogs_vs_cats/test/',
                                          class_mode='binary', batch_size=64, target_size=(224, 224))
    # fit model

   
    history = model.fit_generator(train_it, steps_per_epoch=len(train_it),
                                  validation_data=test_it, validation_steps=len(test_it), epochs=10, verbose=1)
    # evaluate model
    _, acc = model.evaluate_generator(test_it, steps=len(test_it), verbose=1)
    print('> %.3f' % (acc * 100.0))
    # learning curves
    summarize_diagnostics(history)
    model.save('Transfer_Learning_Model.h5')


# entry point, run the test harness
run_test_harness()
```

Answer (score 0):

A number of issues. The VGG model was trained with pixel values from -1 to +1 so you need to add the following

```
 def scaler(x):
        y=x/127.5-1
        return y
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=scaler)
```

I would remove featurewise_center=True. If you use it you have to run fit on the train set.
In model.fit you have steps_per_epoch=len(train_it) and validation_steps=len(test_it).
Since you set a batch_size of 64 in the generators these values should be
steps_per_epoch=len(train_it.labels)//64 and validaion_steps=len(test_it)/64. Actually in model.fit leave these parameters out. Model.fit will calculate the right values internally. Your validation loss curve indicates a small degree of over fitting. Add a drop out layer after the class1 layer. Set the dropout rate to something like.2.
If you want to push for the highest degree of accuracy I recommend you incorporate two Keras callbacks. The EarlyStopping callback  monitors validation loss and halts training if the loss fails to reduce after 'patience' number of consecutive epochs. Setting restore_best_weights=True will load the weights for the epoch with the lowest validation loss so you don't have to save then reload the weights. Set epochs to a large number to ensure this callback activates. Use the the keras callback ReduceLROnPlateau to automatically adjust the learning rate based on validation loss. The documentation for the callbacks is located [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/) The code I use is shown below

```
es=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping( monitor="val_loss", patience=3,
                                     verbose=1,  restore_best_weights=True)
rlronp=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau( monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=1,
                                             verbose=1)
callbacks=[es, rlronp]
```

in model.fit add callbacks=callbacks